# Compilig PCSX2 on Fedora 30 Help?

Tags: fedora, compiling, gcc

Hi I have try to compile PCSX2 1.6 on fedora 30 and now I'm getting an error on console like this sorry it is down i reach the limit of characters permitted

I'm not sure what it does mean honestly i need help ! it is gcc ? I put all the output but i would like to explain i have gcc 9.3.1 and in the exit you can see a complain you are compiling whit 9.1.x or 9.0.x it could be that ? plus it clomplain about -- Could NOT find Vtune (missing: VTUNE_LIBRARIES VTUNE_INCLUDE_DIRS) but I'm using an AMD then dont need it rigth ? well hope some one can give some of her time thank you!

```
./build.sh --cross-multilib --gtk3
Building pcsx2 with -DCMAKE_BUILD_PO=FALSE -GNinja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=cmake/linux-compiler-i386-multilib.cmake -DGTK3_API=TRUE
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/cc - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/lib64/ccache/c++ - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Build Fedora specific
-- Building with GNU GCC
-- BuildType set to Devel by default
-- Cross compilation is enabled.
-- Compiling a i386 build on a x86_64 host.
-- Found ALSA: /usr/lib/libasound.so (found version "1.2.1.2") 
-- Found PCAP: /usr/lib/libpcap.so  
-- Performing Test PCAP_LINKS_SOLO
-- Performing Test PCAP_LINKS_SOLO - Success
-- Looking for pcap_get_pfring_id
-- Looking for pcap_get_pfring_id - not found
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/libxml2.so (found version "2.9.10") 
-- Found Freetype: /usr/lib/libfreetype.so (found version "2.9.1") 
-- Found Gettext: /usr/bin/msgmerge (found version "0.19.8.1") 
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.21.3") 
-- Looking for lzma_auto_decoder in /usr/lib/liblzma.so
-- Looking for lzma_auto_decoder in /usr/lib/liblzma.so - found
-- Looking for lzma_easy_encoder in /usr/lib/liblzma.so
-- Looking for lzma_easy_encoder in /usr/lib/liblzma.so - found
-- Looking for lzma_lzma_preset in /usr/lib/liblzma.so
-- Looking for lzma_lzma_preset in /usr/lib/liblzma.so - found
-- Found LibLZMA: /usr/lib/liblzma.so (found version "5.2.4") 
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/libOpenGL.so   
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/libpng.so (found version "1.6.36") 
-- Could NOT find Vtune (missing: VTUNE_LIBRARIES VTUNE_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
-- Found wxWidgets: -pthread;;;-lwx_baseu-3.0;-lwx_gtk3u_core-3.0;-lwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0 (found version "3.0.4") 
-- Found Libc: /usr/lib/librt.so;/usr/lib/libdl.so;/usr/lib/libm.so  
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.6.1") 
-- AIO found
-- LIBUDEV found
-- PORTAUDIO found
-- SOUNDTOUCH found
-- SDL2 found
-- Found X11: /usr/include   
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/libX11.so;/usr/lib/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/libX11.so;/usr/lib/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:272 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (GTK3_GTK)
  does not match the name of the calling package (GTK3).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/FindGTK3.cmake:855 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake:126 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found GTK3_GTK: /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so  
-- Found the following HarfBuzz libraries:
--  HarfBuzz (required): /usr/lib/libharfbuzz.so
-- Found HarfBuzz: /usr/include/harfbuzz (found version "2.6.1") 
CMake Warning at cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake:226 (message):
  

      It looks like you are compiling with 9.0.x or 9.1.x. Using these versions is not recommended,
      as there is a bug known to cause the compiler to segfault while compiling. See patch
      https://gitweb.gentoo.org/proj/gcc-patches.git/commit/?id=275ab714637a64672c6630cfd744af2c70957d5a
      Even with that patch, compiling with LTO may still segfault. Use at your own risk!
      This text being in a compile log in an open issue may cause it to be closed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:30 (include)


Using precompiled headers.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/denn0n/pcsx2/pcsx2/build
[1/568] Generating ../da_DK__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[2/568] Generating ../de_DE__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[3/568] Generating ../es_ES__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[4/568] Generating ../ca_ES__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[5/568] Generating ../ar_SA__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[6/568] Generating ../cs_CZ__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[7/568] Generating ../fi_FI__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[8/568] Generating ../fr_FR__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[9/568] Generating ../ja_JP__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[10/568] Generating ../it_IT__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[11/568] Generating ../hr_HR__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[12/568] Generating ../hu_HU__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[13/568] Generating ../id_ID__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[14/568] Generating ../ko_KR__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[15/568] Generating ../lt_LT__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[16/568] Generating ../ms_MY__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[17/568] Generating ../pl_PL__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[18/568] Generating ../nb_NO__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[19/568] Generating ../nl_NL__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[20/568] Generating ../pt_BR__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[21/568] Generating ../sv_SE__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[22/568] Generating ../ru_RU__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[23/568] Generating ../tr_TR__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[24/568] Generating ../zh_TW__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[25/568] Generating ../th_TH__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[26/568] Generating ../ca_ES__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[27/568] Generating ../cs_CZ__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[28/568] Generating ../ar_SA__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[29/568] Generating ../zh_CN__pcsx2_Iconized.gmo
[30/568] Generating ../es_ES__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[31/568] Generating ../de_DE__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[32/568] Generating ../da_DK__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[33/568] Generating ../fi_FI__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[34/568] Generating ../hr_HR__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[35/568] Generating ../id_ID__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[36/568] Generating ../hu_HU__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[37/568] Generating ../ko_KR__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[38/568] Generating ../ja_JP__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[39/568] Generating ../fr_FR__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[40/568] Generating ../it_IT__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[41/568] Generating ../lt_LT__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[42/568] Generating ../ms_MY__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[43/568] Generating ../nb_NO__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[44/568] Generating ../pl_PL__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[45/568] Generating ../pt_BR__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[46/568] Generating ../nl_NL__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[47/568] Generating ../zh_TW__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[48/568] Generating ../sv_SE__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[49/568] Generating ../tr_TR__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[50/568] Generating ../zh_CN__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[51/568] Generating ../ru_RU__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[52/568] Generating ../th_TH__pcsx2_Main.gmo
[53/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/AlignedMalloc.cpp.o
[54/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/Console.cpp.o
[55/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/VirtualMemory.cpp.o
[56/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/EventSource.cpp.o
[57/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/FastFormatString.cpp.o
[58/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/Exceptions.cpp.o
[59/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/Linux/LnxHostSys.cpp.o
[60/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/IniInterface.cpp.o
[61/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/CheckedStaticBox.cpp.o
[62/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/Mutex.cpp.o
[63/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/Perf.cpp.o
[64/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/PrecompiledHeader.cpp.o
[65/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/PathUtils.cpp.o
[66/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/pxCheckBox.cpp.o
[67/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/pxRadioPanel.cpp.o
[68/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/pxStaticText.cpp.o
[69/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/pxTranslate.cpp.o
[70/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/pxStreams.cpp.o
[71/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/pxWindowTextWriter.cpp.o
[72/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/RwMutex.cpp.o
[73/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/StringHelpers.cpp.o
[74/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/wxGuiTools.cpp.o
[75/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/ThreadTools.cpp.o
[76/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/ThreadingDialogs.cpp.o
[77/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/wxAppWithHelpers.cpp.o
[78/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/Linux/LnxThreads.cpp.o
[79/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/wxHelpers.cpp.o
[80/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/Linux/LnxMisc.cpp.o
[81/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/VirtualMemory.cpp.o
[82/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/AlignedMalloc.cpp.o
[83/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities_NO_TLS.dir/Semaphore.cpp.o
[84/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/Console.cpp.o
[85/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/CheckedStaticBox.cpp.o
[86/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/EventSource.cpp.o
[87/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/FastFormatString.cpp.o
[88/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/Exceptions.cpp.o
[89/568] Linking CXX static library common/src/Utilities/libUtilities_NO_TLS.a
[90/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/IniInterface.cpp.o
[91/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/Linux/LnxHostSys.cpp.o
[92/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/PrecompiledHeader.cpp.o
[93/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/Mutex.cpp.o
[94/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/PathUtils.cpp.o
[95/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/Perf.cpp.o
[96/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/pxStreams.cpp.o
[97/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/pxStaticText.cpp.o
[98/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/pxRadioPanel.cpp.o
[99/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/pxCheckBox.cpp.o
[100/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/pxWindowTextWriter.cpp.o
[101/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/pxTranslate.cpp.o
[102/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/RwMutex.cpp.o
[103/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/StringHelpers.cpp.o
[104/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/ThreadTools.cpp.o
[105/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/ThreadingDialogs.cpp.o
[106/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/wxGuiTools.cpp.o
[107/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/wxAppWithHelpers.cpp.o
[108/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/wxHelpers.cpp.o
[109/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/Linux/LnxThreads.cpp.o
[110/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/Linux/LnxMisc.cpp.o
[111/568] Building CXX object common/src/Utilities/CMakeFiles/Utilities.dir/Semaphore.cpp.o
[112/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/bmi.cpp.o
[113/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/cpudetect.cpp.o
[114/568] Linking CXX static library common/src/Utilities/libUtilities.a
[115/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/fpu.cpp.o
[116/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/groups.cpp.o
[117/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/jmp.cpp.o
[118/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/legacy.cpp.o
[119/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/legacy_sse.cpp.o
[120/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/movs.cpp.o
[121/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/x86emitter.cpp.o
[122/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/PrecompiledHeader.cpp.o
[123/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/simd.cpp.o
[124/568] Building CXX object plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/TocStuff.cpp.o
[125/568] Building CXX object plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/CDVD.cpp.o
[126/568] Building CXX object plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/ReadThread.cpp.o
[127/568] Building CXX object common/src/x86emitter/CMakeFiles/x86emitter.dir/LnxCpuDetect.cpp.o
[128/568] Building CXX object plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/Settings.cpp.o
[129/568] Linking CXX static library common/src/x86emitter/libx86emitter.a
[130/568] Building CXX object plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/Unix/LinuxIOCtlSrc.cpp.o
[131/568] Building CXX object plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/Unix/LinuxConfig.cpp.o
[132/568] Building CXX object plugins/CDVDnull/CMakeFiles/CDVDnull.dir/CDVD.cpp.o
[133/568] Generating gui/Resources/AppIcon16.h
[134/568] Generating gui/Resources/AppIcon32.h
[135/568] Generating gui/Resources/AppIcon64.h
[136/568] Generating gui/Resources/ButtonIcon_Camera.h
[137/568] Generating gui/Resources/ConfigIcon_Gamefixes.h
[138/568] Generating gui/Resources/ConfigIcon_MemoryCard.h
[139/568] Generating gui/Resources/ConfigIcon_Cpu.h
[140/568] Generating gui/Resources/ConfigIcon_Speedhacks.h
[141/568] Generating gui/Resources/ConfigIcon_Paths.h
[142/568] Generating gui/Resources/ConfigIcon_Plugins.h
[143/568] Generating gui/Resources/Breakpoint_Active.h
[144/568] Generating gui/Resources/Logo.h
[145/568] Generating gui/Resources/Breakpoint_Inactive.h
[146/568] Generating gui/Resources/BackgroundLogo.h
[147/568] Linking CXX shared module plugins/CDVDnull/libCDVDnull.so
FAILED: plugins/CDVDnull/libCDVDnull.so 
: && /usr/lib64/ccache/c++ -m32  -mfxsr -mxsave -march=native -pipe -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -fno-builtin-strcmp -fno-builtin-memcmp -mfpmath=sse -Wall -Wextra -Wno-attributes -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-unused-value  -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-overflow=1  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -Wformat -Wformat-security -ggdb3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -DPCSX2_DEVBUILD -D_DEVEL  -O2    -std=c++11 -Wno-invalid-offsetof -pthread   -shared  -o plugins/CDVDnull/libCDVDnull.so plugins/CDVDnull/CMakeFiles/CDVDnull.dir/CDVD.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:  /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so  /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.so  /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so  /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so && :
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[148/568] Creating gresources XML file (.gresource.xml)
[149/568] Generating gui/Resources/ConfigIcon_Video.h
[150/568] Building CXX object plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/Unix/GtkGui.cpp.o
[151/568] Building CXX object plugins/dev9null/CMakeFiles/dev9null-0.5.0.dir/DEV9.cpp.o
[152/568] Building CXX object plugins/FWnull/CMakeFiles/FWnull-0.7.0.dir/FW.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[1/418] Linking CXX shared module plugins/FWnull/libFWnull-0.7.0.so
FAILED: plugins/FWnull/libFWnull-0.7.0.so 
: && /usr/lib64/ccache/c++ -m32  -mfxsr -mxsave -march=native -pipe -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -fno-builtin-strcmp -fno-builtin-memcmp -mfpmath=sse -Wall -Wextra -Wno-attributes -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-unused-value  -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-overflow=1  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -Wformat -Wformat-security -ggdb3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -DPCSX2_DEVBUILD -D_DEVEL  -O2    -std=c++11 -Wno-invalid-offsetof -pthread   -shared  -o plugins/FWnull/libFWnull-0.7.0.so plugins/FWnull/CMakeFiles/FWnull-0.7.0.dir/FW.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:  /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so  /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.so  /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so  /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so && :
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[2/418] Linking CXX shared module plugins/CDVDnull/libCDVDnull.so
FAILED: plugins/CDVDnull/libCDVDnull.so 
: && /usr/lib64/ccache/c++ -m32  -mfxsr -mxsave -march=native -pipe -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -fno-builtin-strcmp -fno-builtin-memcmp -mfpmath=sse -Wall -Wextra -Wno-attributes -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-unused-value  -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-overflow=1  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -Wformat -Wformat-security -ggdb3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -DPCSX2_DEVBUILD -D_DEVEL  -O2    -std=c++11 -Wno-invalid-offsetof -pthread   -shared  -o plugins/CDVDnull/libCDVDnull.so plugins/CDVDnull/CMakeFiles/CDVDnull.dir/CDVD.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:  /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so  /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.so  /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so  /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so && :
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[3/418] Generating resources.c
[4/418] Linking CXX shared module plugins/dev9null/libdev9null-0.5.0.so
FAILED: plugins/dev9null/libdev9null-0.5.0.so 
: && /usr/lib64/ccache/c++ -m32  -mfxsr -mxsave -march=native -pipe -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -fno-builtin-strcmp -fno-builtin-memcmp -mfpmath=sse -Wall -Wextra -Wno-attributes -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-unused-value  -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-overflow=1  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -Wformat -Wformat-security -ggdb3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -DPCSX2_DEVBUILD -D_DEVEL  -O2    -std=c++11 -Wno-invalid-offsetof -pthread   -shared  -o plugins/dev9null/libdev9null-0.5.0.so plugins/dev9null/CMakeFiles/dev9null-0.5.0.dir/DEV9.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:  /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so  /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.so  /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so  /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so && :
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[5/418] Linking CXX shared module plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/libcdvdGigaherz.so
FAILED: plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/libcdvdGigaherz.so 
: && /usr/lib64/ccache/c++ -m32  -mfxsr -mxsave -march=native -pipe -fvisibility=hidden -pthread -fno-builtin-strcmp -fno-builtin-memcmp -mfpmath=sse -Wall -Wextra -Wno-attributes -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-unused-value  -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-overflow=1  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -Wformat -Wformat-security -ggdb3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -DPCSX2_DEVBUILD -D_DEVEL  -O2    -std=c++11 -Wno-invalid-offsetof -pthread   -shared  -o plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/libcdvdGigaherz.so plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/CDVD.cpp.o plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/ReadThread.cpp.o plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/Settings.cpp.o plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/TocStuff.cpp.o plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/Unix/GtkGui.cpp.o plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/Unix/LinuxConfig.cpp.o plugins/cdvdGigaherz/src/CMakeFiles/cdvdGigaherz.dir/Unix/LinuxIOCtlSrc.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib:  /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so  /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so  /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpango-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so  /usr/local/lib/libpangoxft-1.0.so  /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so  /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so  /usr/lib/librt.so  /usr/lib/libdl.so  /usr/lib/libm.so  /usr/lib/libudev.so && :
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libatk-1.0.so: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[6/418] Building CXX object pcsx2/CMakeFiles/PCSX2.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.gch
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Do you really need it compiled by yourself, have any customizations of yours? If not, add Rpmfusion repo and then you can install it with just one command.

Comment: `dnf install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 1:25:02 ago on Wed 17 Jun 2020 06:24:21 PM EDT.
Package rpmfusion-free-release-30-1.noarch is already installed.
Package rpmfusion-nonfree-release-30-1.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

dnf search pcsx2
Last metadata expiration check: 1:25:29 ago on Wed 17 Jun 2020 06:24:21 PM EDT.
No matches found.`

Comment: i have try to install like that was my first option i'm compiling since look the only way to have it !

Comment: if i do  `dnf install pcsx2 ` i get install a file rpmfusion-nonfree-obsolete-packages-30-1.fc30.noarch i dont know whats do mean bbut i cant run pcsx2 or get an launcher in the menu